# Velocity.js color change not animating on mobile

Tags: javascript, velocity.js

I have a Velocity.js script that animates color changes for navigation between sections in a fullpage.js implementation. For some reason or another, while the color change works on desktop, it's not working on Safari mobile. Here's part of the code.

```
 var script = [
  {
    e: itemToAnimate,
    p: {
        color: "#ffffff"
    },
    o: {
        duration: duratianVar
    }
}];
```

Comment: Seems you'll have to provide much more information / code.

Comment: Please provide code using the proper arguments - http://velocityjs.org/#arguments